# how to hold objects in array in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can we have array of our own objects in hadoop?  Does Hadoop have containers like List, Set, LinkedList etc. similar to java? Are the following lines good?

```
Text[] textArray = new Text[2];
textArray[0] = new Text(maxSalaryDeptEmployee.getEmployeeName());
textArray[1] = new Text(Integer.toString(maxSalaryDeptEmployee.getEmployeeSalary()));
ArrayWritable arrayWritable = new ArrayWritable(Text.class,textArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet looks good. Hadoop by default supports only ArrayWritable, ArrayPrimitiveWritable, TwoDArrayWritable, MapWritable, SortedMapWritable and EnumSetWritable as "containers".

You can also implement custom Writables, a good reference is [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html).